# How to replace Matlab blockproc in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have part of metlab function, that multiply two matrices by 8,8 block. Table1 is 8x8 shape, table2 is 320x240 shape. I want to transmofr below code to python.

```
fun = @(x)x.data .*table1;
I_spatial = blockproc(table2,[8 8],fun);
```

I want to use method to multiply matricies like np.dot, but sizes of input arrays is not the same in row-column connection, so I cannot do it easily. Can somebody could help me, how can I port that fragment to Python?
Also I have second part of this function

```
fun=@(x)idct2(x.data);
I_spatial = blockproc(I_spatial,[8 8],fun)+128;
```

How can I write that part in Python?

Answer (score 2):

Using Ahmed's function and example:

```
In [284]: a = np.ones([320, 240])
     ...: b = np.zeros([8, 8])
     ...: 
     ...: 
     ...: def func_mul(x):
     ...:     return x @ b
In [285]: result = blockproc(a, 8, 8, func_mul)
In [286]: result.shape
Out[286]: (320, 240)
```

In a comment I suggested reshaping/transposing the `a` to a (n,m,8,8) array:

```
In [287]: a1 = a.reshape(40, 8, 30, 8).transpose(0, 2, 1, 3)
In [288]: a1.shape
Out[288]: (40, 30, 8, 8)
In [289]: res = a1 @ b           # matmul does 'batch' on lead dimensions
In [290]: res.shape
Out[290]: (40, 30, 8, 8)
In [291]: res1 = res.transpose(0, 2, 1, 3).reshape(a.shape)
```

Compare times:

```
In [292]: timeit result = blockproc(a, 8, 8, func_mul)
10.2 ms ± 171 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


In [293]: def foo(a, b):
     ...:     a1 = a.reshape(40, 8, 30, 8).transpose(0, 2, 1, 3)
     ...:     res = a1 @ b
     ...:     res1 = res.transpose(0, 2, 1, 3).reshape(a.shape)
     ...:     return res1

In [294]: timeit foo(a,b)
918 µs ± 2.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Changing the arrays so the result values are significant (not all 0) to verify the equality of these methods:

```
In [295]: a = np.arange(320 * 240).reshape(320, 240)
In [296]: b = np.arange(64).reshape(8, 8)
In [297]: result = blockproc(a, 8, 8, func_mul)
In [298]: res1 = foo(a, b)
In [299]: np.allclose(result, res1)
Out[299]: True
```

My approach is much faster because it does not iterate on the lead (40,30) dimensions.  But it depends on the `func` being something like `matmul` that can work with this mix of dimension.  In other words, a function that makes full use of `numpy` `broadcasting`.

### edit

And @Victor's version:

```
In [308]: def victor(A, blockdims, func):
     ...:     vr, hr = A.shape[0] // blockdims[0], A.shape[1] // blockdims[1]
     ...:     B = A.copy()
     ...:     verts = np.vsplit(B, vr)
     ...:     for i in range(len(verts)):
     ...:         for j, v in enumerate(np.hsplit(verts[i], hr)):
     ...:             B[
     ...:                 i * blockdims[0] : (i + 1) * blockdims[0],
     ...:                 j * blockdims[1] : (j + 1) * blockdims[1],
     ...:             ] = func(v)
     ...:     return B
     ...: 
In [309]: res2 = victor(a, (8, 8), func_mul)
In [310]: res2.shape
Out[310]: (320, 240)
In [311]: np.allclose(result, res2)
Out[311]: True
In [312]: timeit res2 = victor(a, (8, 8), func_mul)
13.7 ms ± 5.51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

there aren't any premade versions I am aware of, but this implementation will be quite fast, as data copying is minimal, granted that it'll always pad the output to be of the proper size.

```py
def blockproc(A,m,n,fun):

    results_rows = []
    for y in range(0,A.shape[0],m):
        results_cols = []
        for x in range(0,A.shape[1],n):
            results_cols.append(fun(A[y:y+m,x:x+n]))
        results_rows.append(results_cols)

    patch_rows = results_rows[0][0].shape[0]
    patch_cols = results_rows[0][0].shape[1]
    final_array_cols = results_rows[0][0].shape[1] * len(results_rows[0])
    final_array_rows = results_rows[0][0].shape[0] * len(results_rows)

    final_array = np.zeros([final_array_rows,final_array_cols],dtype=results_rows[0][0].dtype)
    for y in range(len(results_rows)):
        for x in range(len(results_rows[y])):
            data = results_rows[y][x]
            final_array[y*patch_rows:y*patch_rows+data.shape[0],x*patch_cols:x*patch_cols+data.shape[1]] = data

    return final_array
```

testing it:

```py
a = np.ones([320,240])
b = np.zeros([8,8])

def func_mul(x):
    return x@b


result = blockproc(a,8,8,func_mul)
print('dims:',result.shape)

import time
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    blockproc(a, 8, 8, func_mul)
    pass
t2 = time.time()
print('time:',(t2-t1)/1000)
```

> dims:(320, 240)
>
> time:0.006634121179580689

Answer (score 1):

Like @Ahmed AEK mentioned, there is no built-in solution for this. I have come up with a solution that leverages `numpy`'s extremely optimized [`vsplit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vsplit.html) and [`hsplit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html) functions and even allows you to perform the function inplace:

```py
    import scipy
import numpy as np
from typing import *
from scipy.fftpack import idct


npd = NewType('npd', np.ndarray)
id = lambda x: x # default function is nothing
def blockproc(A: npd, blockdims: Tuple[int, int], func: Callable[npd, Any]=id, inplace: bool = False)-> npd:
        blocks: List[npd] = []
        if A.shape[0]%blockdims[0] != 0 or A.shape[1]%blockdims[1] != 0:
                print(f"Invalid block dimensions - {A.shape} must be divided evenly by {tuple(blockdims)}")
        vr, hr = A.shape[0]//blockdims[0], A.shape[1]//blockdims[1]

        B = A if inplace else A.copy()
        verts: List[npd] = np.vsplit(B,vr)
        try:
                for i in range(len(verts)):
                        for j,v in enumerate(np.hsplit(verts[i], hr)):
                                B[i*blockdims[0]:(i+1)*blockdims[0], j*blockdims[1]: (j+1)*blockdims[1]] = func(h)
        except Exception as e: print("Invalid block function"); exit(e)
        return B


if __name__ == "__main__":
        # Assume table1 and table2 are defined above ...
        
        # First code sample
        fun = lambda x: x@table1
        I_spatial = blockproc(table2 ,[8,8], fun)

        # Second code sample
        fun = lambda x: idct(x)
        I_spatial = blockproc(I_spatial,[8 8],fun) + 128
```

Look at the two code samples you provided - nearly identical! If you're curious, click here for more info about [`idct`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.idct.html)

EDIT:

Per @Ahmed AEK's comments (see below), it appears `enumerate` is slowing down the code significantly. I've now removed the outer `enumerate` in an effort to decrease runtime.

Comment: there's a lot of data copying done by vsplit and hsplit, which is why I didn't recommend using them, my implementation is actually 30% faster due to less data copying, but your function is better formatted.

Comment: @AhmedAEK interesting, I didn’t know that! That’s pretty impressive, usually numpy is super optimized. I don’t have a ton of experience with vsplit and hsplit specifically - would you mind linking some sort of documentation/discussion about the data copying they do?

Comment: apparently, vsplit and hsplit also use memory views, and don't copy data, which makes me wonder about the reason for the 30% difference in speed.

Comment: @AhmedAEK yeah numpy is famous for using views rather than copies, so that makes sense. The 30% thing is curious though - could it be the .copy() function itself? How are you timing it ?

Comment: i just make each function run 1000 times in a row (which takes roughly 6.5 seconds for my function and 10 seconds for yours) and changing copy to np.zeros only brings your function down to 9 seconds, so the problem has to be from either enumerate or v/hsplit.

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem is enumerate - let me make a quick change and see if it gets faster

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242881/discussion-between-victor-von-doom-and-ahmed-aek).

Comment: `vsplit` ends up calling `array_split`; since it returns a list of arrays it has to iterate.  Sure it makes `views`.   A list comprehension is just as good, maybe even faster: `larr[x:x+n,:] for x in range(0,stop,step)]`